Не вводятся данные с клавиатуры в Visual studio С++
Не получается ввести какие-либо данные. Выскакивает ошибка о том, что язык не поддерживается.
введите сюда описание изображения//i.sstatic.net/otG5FUA4.png

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

¿Это случайно не Visual Studio Code?

Да, это Visual studio Code
